# Herkunft und Etymologie von "umgehend"

Tags: etymology

Das Adjektiv *umgehend* bedeutet laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/umgehend) "sofort, so schnell wie möglich, ohne jede Verzögerung erfolgend". Es scheint mir nicht klar, was diese Bedeutung mit dem Verb *umgehen* zu tun hat. Der Duden erwähnt nichts über die Herkunft, und [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/umgehend) gibt nur an, dass *umgehend* das Mittelwort der Gegenwart zu *umgehen* ist, was auch nicht hilfreich ist.

Wie kommen die Wörter *umgehen* und *umgehend* zu solchen verschiedenen Bedeutungen? Oder sind die Bedeutungen irgendwie verwandt?

Comment: Wiktionary listet leider nur die Bedeutung vom Verb _umgéhen_; weil _úmgehend_ aber auf der ersten Silbe betont wird, müsste man sich das Verb _úmgehen_ mal ansehen (wie in "Die Angst geht um.")

Comment: ich sehe gerade: Wiktionary listet doch die zweite Bedeutung - hab nicht genau hingeschaut.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Ausdruck [„umgehend“](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/umgehend) *(sofort, so schnell wie möglich, ohne jede Verzögerung erfolgend)* ist eine Verkürzung der Fügung „mit umgehender Post“ im Briefverkehr. (Laut *Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen* von dtv stammt die Fügung aus dem 18. Jahrhundert.) Das Verb „umgehen“ bedeutet hier „umkehren“. Wenn man also beispielsweise eine Antwort „mit umgehender Post“ erwartet hatte, bedeutete das eine Antwort gleich mit der zurückfahrenden Post.

Vergleichbar ist der Ausdruck [„postwendend“](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/postwendend) *(unverzüglich, sofort, umgehend)*.

Comment: Sehr überzeugend. Eine anderer Wortlaut wäre, "umkehren" im Sinne von "sich von der jetzigen Tätigkeit abwenden und sofort um die besagte Sache kümmern". Auch "umkehren" im religiösen Sinne (Busse tun <-> vom schlechten [in diesem Zusammenhang: nicht mehr erwünschten] Weg umkehren) scheint mir dabei passend zu sein.

Answer (score 5):

[Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GU03619) erklärt, "umgehend" habe sich in der Bedeutung "sofort" vom Verb gelöst, und die Herkunft komme von dem Ausdruck "mit umgehender Post": Also mit der zurückgehenden Post, d.h. direkt im Anschluss an den Empfang eines Briefes.

Answer (score 0):

[Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/umgehen_ausweichen_herumgehen) listet folgende Bedeutungen für "umgehen" auf:

- aus dem Weg gehen
- ausweichen
- fernhalten
- vermeiden
- meiden

Hierbei ist das Subjekt der Handlung des Umgehens die Ablenkung / Aufhaltung, die einen von der sofortigkeit einer Reaktion / Handlung abhält.

> Mein Vater ist ins Spital gebracht worden. Ich reagiere umgehend (fahre zu ihm ins Spital). Ich umgehe alles, was sich mir in den Weg stellt. Ich umgehe jede Begegnung mit Personen. Ich umgehe jede Ablenkung, ohne mich auf sie einzulassen (auf sie EINzugehen).

Comment: müsste es dann nicht *umgéhend* heißen und nicht *úmgehend*?

Comment: Ja. "úmgehend" wäre das Adjektiv zum (guten / sittlichen) "Umgang". `Ich gehe behutsam mit der Vase um.`

Comment: Ja, aber *úmgehend* ist doch gerade die Betonung des Wortes, das auch "sofort" bedeutet.

Comment: Hast recht, "umgéhend" scheint lediglich das "um etwas herum gehen" im wortwörtlichen Sinne zu bezeichnen ... frage mich jetzt, ob dann "umgehen" (der [gute / sittliche] Umgang) identisch zum hier behandelten "umgehend" ausgesprochen wird, wobei letzteres mit seinem "d" ein Adjektiv ist.